# 400 bad request while passing multi-part form data to Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, html, spring

I have a form containing some text fields and a file upload facility. Here's what it looks like:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/spn/submitReclaimForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="ReclaimForm" modelAttribute="reclaimForm">
```

Here's the corresponding controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RECLIAM_FORM_SUBMIT_URL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addStudent(@ModelAttribute("ReclaimForm") ReclaimForm form, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();      
    mav.setViewName(URLConstant.COMPLAINT_REGISTERED);
    return mav;
}
```

The RecliamForm class contains fields that are all strings.

**The problem**: When I submit the form, it shows  a 400 bad request error code. What is it that I might be doing wrong?

I have already defined the bean as:

```
bean id="multipartResolver" 
class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does the server log say when the error occurs?

Comment: "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present"

Comment: Ah. Solved it. Forgot to name my input as "file".